# Is there an excel function to make a spine chart (Public Health England Profiles)

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am trying to create this kind of range graph (Public Health England is calling it a "spine graph". Is there a way to create this? The website allows us to export a raw data which includes value, lower CI (95.0 limit), upper CI (95.0 limit) for England, Region and local authority.

https://fingertips.phe.org.uk/profile/health-profiles/data#page/1/gid/1938132701/pat/6/par/E12000007/ati/202/are/E09000008/iid/90366/age/1/sex/1/cat/-1/ctp/-1/yrr/3/cid/4/tbm/1

https://fingertips.phe.org.uk/documents/PHDS%20Guidance%20-%20Spine%20Charts.pdf

[Graph photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBTp8.png)

Comment: This is quite complex and is a kind of one-off thing. There are an almost infinite number of similar charts with different ways to visualize similar data. There's nothing out of the box that does this kind of graphic specifically. Excel developers such as myself could design something for you, since Excel's charting feature is so flexible. But you'll have to probably pay for several hours of work.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this exactly might not be possible in excel without some coding in VBA.

That being said, you might be able to combine a few functions to get similar results:

1. Sparklines is a built-in excel function to graph a line inside a cell
2. Some conditional formatting might be applied to get a stacked bar graph look
3. In cell formulae using the REPT function can be used to move a character like `●` left and right in a single cell, like this `=REPT(" ",A1)&"●"`
4. Worst case you can "chop" the spine into multiple cells, then format each according to conditional formatting.

Comment: Set the font (typeface) of that cell to be one of monospace type (e.g. Courier New) for best results. The percentiles might be possible to display using other characters e.g. `...<---●---->...`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible (with no VBA or Add-ons).

[image]

However, to do it will be quite complex.  Two specific things that make this challenging to complete in a single chart:

1. The horizontal axis has to change direction (polarity in their documentation) based on the data being charted.
2. The charted values include a combination of decimals and percentages.

There are a couple strategies to simplify the process:

1. Separate all of the values by the two categories above and create charts for each class of item.
2. Use a different chart type that has the same characteristics, but is supported by Excel (e.g. box and whiskers)
3. Use an add-on that provides graphics with similar characteristics (e.g. bullet sparklines in the excellent [Sparklines for Excel](http://sparklines-excel.blogspot.com/) by Fabrice Rimlinger).

However, if you want to most closely follow the Spine Chart (as defined by Public Health of England) the strategy you'll want to use is to convert all of your values to a percentage of the range you need and plot the percentages.

1. **Scale:** I'd convert them to a scale of -1 to 1, with 0 being your spine; this will make addressing polarity easier.
2. **Chart Type:** You'll need a combination chart with your quartiles being stacked bars, and your markers being a scatter chart.
3. **Markers:** If you want different colored markers for significance, you'll need a series for each significance level and using nulls for the unused levels for each point.

This will be difficult to setup (and will require several helper columns), but once you have the format, it should be relatively easy to extend or duplicate.